# play a movie using a system command and continue with auditory stimuli presentation

Tags: matlab, vlc

I am writing a script for an experiment where  movie + auditory stimuli will be presented simultaneously. 
So, at some point in the script there is this command to play the video:

```
system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC.exe" --play-and-exit instructionsANDstimuli\Donald.mp4 --qt-minimal-view --no-qt-name-in-title --fullscreen --width 400 --height 300 --start-time 90 --stop-time 100  --no-osd --no-autoscale --no-keyboard-events --no-mouse-events --intf dummy --dummy-quiet');
```

I would like to find a way to let the movie play and return to the rest of the script before the movie ends.
Is there a simple way to not wait for a system() command to finish?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Probably a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890167/executing-system-command-in-matlab-without-waiting

Comment: @Navan you were right, thank you!